# Umlaut character support in java mailapi

Tags: java, jakarta-mail

```
MimeBodyPart mimebodypart = new MimeBodyPart();
DataSource datasource = new FileDataSource(file);
mimebodypart.setDataHandler(new DataHandler(datasource));
//mimebodypart.setFileName(MimeUtility.encodeText(file.getName(), "UTF-8", null));
mimebodypart.setFileName(file.getName());
```

In the above code I have the file name as *PDF testöäüßÜÄÖtest DEV2 - 13.06.2016.tiff*
The attachment is coming as untitled_000000456.tiff
<000000456> is a random number that is showing up.

Using **stöäüßÜÄÖ** is working fine but when the string is one more character long i.e ***e*stöäüßÜÄÖ** it is not working.

Also öäüßÜÄÖöäüßÜÄÖ and testtesttest   (any length) is working.

Could anyone please point out what I am doing wrong?

I am using JavaMail API JAR » 1.5.6

**https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.mail/javax.mail-api/1.5.6**

java Version 1.8

**EDIT**

After the some headers I am able to get the proper filename but the message body is missing. Here is the updated code.

```
try {
    Message message = new MimeMessage(Session.getInstance(System.getProperties()));
    message.setHeader("MIME-Version", "1.0");
    message.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=\""+ file.getName() +"\""); 
    //file.getName() returns PDF "testöäüßÜÄÖtest DEV2 - 13.06.2016.tiff"
    message.saveChanges();

    String email_subject = "subject";
    message.setSubject(email_subject, "UTF-8", null));
    message.setSentDate(new Date());

    MimeBodyPart content = new MimeBodyPart();
    String msg_body = "Message body";
    content.setContent("<p style=font-style:italic;font-size:20px>"+ msg_body +" </p>", "text/html;charset=UTF-8");
    Multipart multipart = new MimeMultipart();
    multipart.addBodyPart(content);



    MimeBodyPart attachment = new MimeBodyPart();
    DataSource source = new FileDataSource(file); //file is of type File 
    attachment.setDataHandler(new DataHandler(source));
    multipart.addBodyPart(attachment);

    message.setContent(multipart);
    message.getFlags().add(Flags.Flag.DRAFT);

    OutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(fileName);
    //fileName.getName() returns PDF testöäüßÜÄÖtest DEV2 - 13.06.2016.eml
    message.writeTo(out);
    out.close();
    out=null;
}catch (Exception ex) {
    ex.printStackTrace();
}
```

What I am doing wrong that the body is missing?

Comment: Try JavaMail 1.6.1 and see if it makes a difference.  If that doesn't help, show us what the MIME headers for the attachment look like by using `message.writeTo(System.out)`.

Comment: JavaMail 1.6.1  is not working in my project. Hence, I am not able to try it.

Comment: I'd like to get more details about your problems with JavaMail 1.6.1 at javamail_ww@oracle.com.  But for this problem, can you show us the MIME headers?

Comment: @BillShannon I was not using any explicit MIME headers. But after adding them, it is now working. Thanks for pointing it out.
About JavaMail 1.6.1, using this the code is not going beyond 
Message message = new MimeMessage(Session.getInstance(System.getProperties()));

There is no exception or log. If I find something shareable, I will email  to you.

Thanks for helping out.

Comment: What MIME headers did you add?

Comment: @BillShannon Please check the edited part. I have mentioned the header there. Also that is removing the message body.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this simpler and more correct version:

```
Message message = new MimeMessage(Session.getInstance(System.getProperties()));

String email_subject = "subject";
message.setSubject(email_subject, "UTF-8");
message.setSentDate(new Date());

MimeBodyPart content = new MimeBodyPart();
String msg_body = "Message body";
content.setText("<p style=font-style:italic;font-size:20px>"+ msg_body +" </p>", "UTF-8", "html");
Multipart multipart = new MimeMultipart();
multipart.addBodyPart(content);

MimeBodyPart attachment = new MimeBodyPart();
attachment.attachFile(file);
multipart.addBodyPart(attachment);

message.setContent(multipart);
message.setFlags(new Flags(Flags.Flag.DRAFT), true);

OutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(fileName);
message.saveChanges();
message.writeTo(out);
out.close();
```

If that doesn't work, post the contents of the file referenced by `fileName`.

Comment: This din't worked. Here is the file as you requested
https://drive.google.com/open?id=1Or5GTg2BZdcGxC7WTonpyu63WCxtTysQ

Comment: That file includes both the message body and the attachment file name.  What exactly didn't work?  Note that the file name is encoded using RFC 2231.  If your mail reader doesn't support that properly, the name may not display correctly.  See [this JavaMail FAQ entry for more information](https://javaee.github.io/javamail/FAQ#encodefilename).

Comment: What exactly didn't work?  - The filename is not rendered properly.
I read the FAQ and tried setting the fileName with Mime Encode. But still it is not working.

Comment: Rendered where, how, with what mailer?  Since the file name is being transmitted correctly, it is most likely a problem with the mailer being used to render the file name.

Comment: I am creating an .eml file that contains the attachment with name PDF testöäüßÜÄÖtest DEV2 - 13.06.2016.tiff using the mailapi which is then saved in the file system. This .eml file is opened using MS Outlook. There the attachment name is "Untitled Attachment.tiff" 

It is required to be PDF testöäüßÜÄÖtest DEV2 - 13.06.2016.tiff instead of Untitled Attachment.tiff

Comment: If you've tried all the techniques above to encode the file name and Outlook doesn't display any of them correctly then the bug is in Outlook and you should contact Microsoft to report that bug.  Have you tried to create such a message in Outlook and save it to a .eml file using Outlook?

Comment: Yes. I have tried to create that message from outlook. It is working fine over there. I have used mailAPI 1.4. mailAPI1.4 is also working fine. So I think mailAPI 1.6 is having the issue.

Comment: What is the different in the headers that specify the attachment file name between the message created by Outlook, the message created by JavaMail 1.4, and the message created by JavaMail 1.6 using each of the techniques described above?